# How to filter data in graphite

Tags: wildcard, metrics, graphite, statsd

I run statsd/graphite for my stats. My stats might look like

```
a.b.c.u1 = 13
a.b.c.u2 = 16
a.b.c.u3 = 18
a.b.c.u4 = 20
a.b.c.u5 = 21
a.b.c.u6 = 22
```

I want to get all  `a.b.c.$u` with value >= 20.

How do I do that with graphite functions??

Answer (score 6):

> [currentAbove](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.currentAbove)(seriesList, n)

Takes one metric or a wildcard seriesList followed by an integer N. Out of all metrics passed, draws only the metrics whose value is above N at the end of the time period specified.

```
&target=currentAbove(server*.instance*.threads.busy,50)
Draws the servers with more than 50 busy threads.
```

In your case, this will become-

```
currentAbove(a.b.c.u*,20)
```